# How to update Xamarin.iOS on Windows

Tags: windows-10

I have [Xamarin.iOS](https://www.xamarin.com) version 10.0.1.10 on Mac and Xamarin.iOS version 10.0.0.1 on Windows 10.

I have to make these versions same. How can I update the Xamarin manually on Windows 10?

Comment: Have you verified the versions on both OSs are actually the same?  Have you downloaded the package and installed it?

Comment: my reason is the reason I voted to close this question.  Since Xamarin is now part of Visual Studio be sure Visual Studio has been updated

Comment: Why you want to close my question ? There is not an option to update Xamarin.iOS in Visual Studio.

Comment: Excuse me, I couldn't understand your English while saying, verify. As I understand, I surely verify it, so they are different as I say the different version numbers in question. But is there a tool, that I miss, to verify ?

Comment: I want you to verify, that the current version of Xamarin.iOS on Windows, is `10.0.0.1` or `10.0.0.10`.  I want you to verify, that if you install the current version of Xamarin.iOS, what version you end up with. I also want you to verify your running the current version of Visual Studio with all released updates.  I want you to edit your question, to include all this information, only then will your question be clear.

Comment: OP asked a simple direct question.  I came here from google looking for the answer to his question and found typical stack exchange 'helpfulness'.  If you don't know the answer ignore the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update visual studio and it should update automatically.

If for some reason you don't want to do that check out the release page: https://releases.xamarin.com/